# correct usage referencing names

Tags: grammar, commas

a) **Regeneration charity**, The Auckland Project, in Bishop Auckland, said it is planning a significant restructure following the events.

Is regeneration charity considered a precise identifier here or would the comma usage be peripheral/optional?

Or should 'The or A' be used at the beginning so it reads as a complete sentence leaving 'The Auckland Project' as a non-essential subject?

It says on some resources if the sentence begins with a determiner such as the or a then the subject is non-essential and can take commas. In this instance, it appears wrong, but perhaps correct with: The regeneration charity, The Auckland Project, ect.

But this contradicts intepreting the precise name of the subject as essential/non essential, asking instead to just be able to read it as complete sentence.

For context: The Auckland Project is simply a charity aimed at revitalising an English town: Bishop Auckland. They are called regeneration charities as they aim to encourage money and spending in towns that aren't doing well and struggling.

Comment: Can you split this into two questions One about the the charity (that needs work because It isn't clear now) and one about Sian.

Answer (score 2):

I have no idea what a) is about.

For the question about the girlfriend, in the sentence after you've identified her, you should use the pronoun "she":
d) His death came about after his girlfriend, Sian Ellis, tragically died. **She** was due to graduate later that year.

In later paragraphs, it might be better to refer to her as "Ms Ellis", unless there is some reason to refer to her familiarly by her first name.

Comment: BBC news bulletins - not to their credit - typically use short cuts such as: **John Smith has announced new health measures. The minister was speaking at.....** leaving the listener to assume that John Smith and the minister are the same person. It is likely, if regrettable, that others will follow suit.

Comment: The only sensible interpretation I can make of a) at all is that the lowercase *charity* is a typo, and the actual name of the single entity is *Regeneration Charity, The Auckland Project*. Because it's certainly nonsensical if *Regeneration charity* is not part of the name, but simply two common nouns at the start of the sentence.

Comment: No its definitely just The Auckland Project. It says on some resources if the sentence begins with a determiner such as the or a then the subject is non-essential and can take commas. In this instance, it appears wrong, but perhaps correct with: The regeneration charity, The Auckland Project, ect.

Comment: But this contradicts  intepreting the precise name of the subject as essential/non essential, asking instead to just be able to read it as complete sentence.